# Port a js map in dart

Tags: javascript, dart

How can i port this const in dart?

```
const CHANNEL_STATES = {
  closed: "closed",
  errored: "errored",
  joined: "joined",
  joining: "joining",
  leaving: "leaving",
}
```

I need it to call ex.  CHANNEL_STATES.closed
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a class and constant static members:

```
class CHANNEL_STATES {
  static const String closed = "closed";
  static const String errored = "errored";
  static const String joined = "joined";
  static const String joining = "joining";
  static const String leaving = "leaving";
}
```

Comment: But with this mode i can't use them in select case

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for, but a similar map constant in Dart would be:

```dart
const channelStates = const {
  "closed": "closed",
  "errored": "errored",
  "joined": "joined",
  "joining": "joining",
  "leaving": "leaving",
};
```

A Dart map literal can use any object as key, so to use a string as key, you need to quote it. You can't use just an unquoted identifier like in JavaScript.